# Openfire and Windows Azure

Tags: azure, openfire

Has anyone installed OpenFire on Windows Azure before?
Is it easy to create another instance with the OpenFire in it?

Thanks!

Comment: I found the solution. Installing OpenFire on Amazon EC2 micro is easy. I never use linux before, but it's not hard as I thought. Once installed, you can manage the rest using WebUI.

Comment: Yes, EC2 works very nice, but it would be nice to hear a Windows Azure specific answer

Comment: I am having this same issue, I cannot get this working\

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I've installed openFire on both EC2 (Linux) and Azure. It is a painless as you could imagine.

- get a VM
- install java
- install openfire
- install openfire db to SQL azure (connection string syntax below)
- jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SQLAzInstance.database.windows.net:1433/OpenFireSqlDBName;ssl=require
- be sure to allow proper ports through the endpoints tab of the virtual machine in the new azure management portal
- TCP 5222/5223 (std/SSL client connectivity)
- TCP 5269 (server-to-server)
- TCP 9090 (default openfire web ui port, you could change this)

Answer (score 1):

Log into your Windows Azure account.

Create a Machine running Ubuntu 14 LTS

Then go to your SSH client (for Mac and Linux users, you can use the terminal by typing

ssh ***username*@*servername*** e.g. *ssh joel@chatserver.cloudapp.net* ) and for Windows users, you can install [PuTTy](http://www.bitvise.com/download-area) SSH client which comes with BitVise.

log in as an admin by typing

***sudo su***

then update the sever by typing

***apt-get update***

then check for any new releases by typing

***apt-get upgrade***

Then check if java is installed (it is usually not installed anyway) by typing

***java -version***

if it is not installed, install it by typing

***apt-get install default-jre***

accept it to install by typing y to mean yes

wait for it to install

then install openfire by first downloading it. You use the *wget* command to download it directly to your server as below. (at the time of writing, openfire 3.9.3 is the latest version)

***wget -O openfire.deb http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloadServlet?filename=openfire/openfire_3.9.3_all.deb***

Then after it has finished downloading, install it by typing

***dpkg --install openfire.deb***

Before you go to the browser, go to your Windows Azure dashboard

Click on the Virtual Machine you have created

Then click on Endpoints

Add the following end points, they are all of TCP type

Public Port 5222, Private Port 5223 and this is for SSL connectivity

Public Port 5269 and Private port 5269 and this is for server to server connectivity

Public Port 9090 and private port 9090 and this is for openfire web UI

After all this, you are good to go,

Go to your browser and type in your server url and at the end put 9090 e.g.

*chatserver.cloudapp.net:9090*

Hope that helped and happy chatting!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466842/how-to-access-open-fire-from-another-pc

Answer (score 0):

To user default port such as 80 and 443 (replace 5222 and 5223 with 80 and 443 ) use following commands to redirect traffic on linux machine.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 5222 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5222
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 5223 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5223
```