# How To access open fire from another pc

Tags: jquery, cordova, openfire, converse.js

We installed open-fire in window-R2. It worked fine in localhost but when we access from another Pc It give me err "This webpage is not available"
How I we access openfire from anoter PC?
1. we open all port
2. Off Firewall

**Work Fine in localhost..**
[image]

But Not Work on when we accesed from anoter PC

Answer (score 0):

Use your IP address and the port 9090 to access server of another computer.It should work. Both the computer should be in a same network, first check whether you can  find that IP from your pc